# JanusGraph indexing in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, janusgraph

I am using Spark to make a JanusGraph from a data stream, but am having issues indexing and creating properties. I want to create an index by a vertex property called "register_id". I am not sure I'm doing it the right way.

So, here's my code:

```
var gr1 = JanusGraphFactory.open("/Downloads/janusgraph-cassandra.properties")
gr1.close()
// This is done to clear the graph made in every run.
JanusGraphFactory.drop(gr1)
gr1 = JanusGraphFactory.open("/Downloads/janusgraph-cassandra.properties")
var reg_id_prop = gr1.makePropertyKey("register_id").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
var mgmt = gr1.openManagement()
gr1.tx().rollback()
mgmt.buildIndex("byRegId", classOf[Vertex]).addKey(reg_id_prop).buildCompositeIndex()
```

When I run the above, I get an error saying:

> "Vertex with id 5164 was removed".

Also, how do I check if I have vertices with a certain property in the graph or not in Scala. I know in gremlin, `g.V().has('name', 'property_value')` works, but can't figure out how to do this in Scala. I tried Gremlin-Scala but can't seem to find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, still struggling with this. Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `mgmt` object to build the schema, not the `graph` object. You also need to make sure to `mgmt.commit()` the schema updates.

```
gr1 = JanusGraphFactory.open("/Downloads/janusgraph-cassandra.properties")
var mgmt = gr1.openManagement()
var reg_id_prop = mgmt.makePropertyKey("register_id").dataType(classOf[String]).make()
mgmt.buildIndex("byRegId", classOf[Vertex]).addKey(reg_id_prop).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()
```

Refer to the [indexing](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html) docs from JanusGraph.

For your second question on checking for the existence of a vertex using the composite index, you need to finish your traversal with a terminal step. For example, in Java, this would return a boolean value:

```
g.V().has('name', 'property_value').hasNext()
```

Refer to [iterating the traversal](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/gremlin.html#_iterating_the_traversal) docs from JanusGraph.

Reading over the [gremlin-scala README](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/master/README.md#simple-traversals), it looks like it has a few options for terminal steps that you could use like `head`, `headOption`, `toList`, or `toSet`.

```
g.V().has('name', 'property_value').headOption
```

You should also check out the [gremlin-scala-examples](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala-examples) and the gremlin-scala [traversal specification](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/master/gremlin-scala/src/test/scala/gremlin/scala/TraversalSpec.scala).

Comment: `g.V().has('name', 'property_value').hasNext()`
This works in Gremlin, how to do this in Scala?

Comment: updated my answer above with more links to existing documentation

Comment: Thanks, just need clarification with one thing. 

How do I index a graph according to edge properties which are double/arrays? I tried doing it, it's not accepting anything other than a string/integer. Also, on integer, edge indexing does not seem to be working. 

Eg.
`val avg = mgmt.makePropertyKey("avg_val").dataType(classOf[Float]).make()` throws an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a supported data type: float`.Changing the Float to Integer/String makes it work.

Comment: You need to use `classOf[java.lang.Float]` otherwise it will resolve it as a [`scala.Float`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Float.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now. But even after indexing some of the edge properties, I get a indexing warning while running Gremlin queries. Vertex properties indexing is working, edge properties isn't.